# TDD in Python for JSON file read

Tags: python, json, unit-testing

I am using Python to read a JSON file and convert each record into a class instance. I already have a sample JSON file, but for the Python code, I am trying to use test-driven development (TDD) methods for the first time. Here's what the data in my (sample) JSON file look like:

```
[{"Name": "Max", "Breed": "Poodle", "Color": "White", "Age": 8},
 {"Name": "Jack", "Breed": "Corgi", "Color": "Black", "Age": 4},
 {"Name": "Lucy", "Breed": "Labrador Retriever", "Color": "Brown", "Age": 2},
 {"Name": "Bear", "Breed": "German Shepherd", "Color": "Brown", "Age": 6}]
```

I know I want to test for valid entries in each of the arguments for all the instances. For example, I want to check the breed against a tuple of acceptable breeds, and check that age is always given as an integer. Given my total lack of TDD experience, it's not clear to me if the code checking the objects resulting from the JSON import code is *itself* the test, or if I should be using one set of tests for the JSON import code and a separate set to test the instances generated by the import code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are two separate instances.  Testing the JSON load is completely different from testing the loaded json data.  Loading the data should not be complex.  (json.loads).  But if you need to test it, keep it as minimal and fine grained as possible.  Your tests should not affect each other.

In general, your test cases should test *very* specific portions of your code.  That is, it should test specific functionality of your program.  Because you mentioned validating the json data you load (breed for instance), this implies that your program should also have this validate functionality.  For this instance, you would have test cases like the ones below.

```
import doggie

def test_validate_breed():
    # Positive test case -- everything here should pass.  (Assuming you give good data)
    # your load_json routine itself could be a test.  But generally this either works or
    # it raises a json exception...  At any rate, load_json returns a list of dictionaries
    # like those you described above.
    l = load_json()
    for d in l:
        assert doggie.validate_breed(d)

    # Generate an invalid dictionary entry
    d = { "Name": "Some Name", "Breed": "Invalid!", ... }
    assert False == doggie.validate_breed(d)

def test_validate_age():
    l = load_json()
    for d in l:
        assert doggie.validate_age(d)

    # generate an invalid dictionary entry
    d = { "Name": "Some Name", ... , "Age": 1000 }
    assert False == doggie.validate_age(d)
```

The beauty of testing is that it exposes flaws in your design.  It is very good at exposing unnecessary coupling.

I recommend you check out nose for unit testing.  It makes running tests a cinch and provides nice utility functions that better describe test failures.  For instance:

```
>>> import nose.tools as nt
>>> nt.assert_equal(4, 5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\MSFBPY27\lib\unittest\case.py", line 509, in assertEqual
    assertion_func(first, second, msg=msg)
  File "C:\MSFBPY27\lib\unittest\case.py", line 502, in _baseAssertEqual
    raise self.failureException(msg)
AssertionError: 4 != 5
```

Comment: It looks like the tests you've set up are essentially doing two things: 1) applying the validation methods (from doggie.py) on the actual list of dog dicts and 2) running the validation methods on a known invalid dict. Is that a reasonable generalized approach to test design?

Comment: When I test, I want to test one of two things -- generally speaking.  I want to test very specific outputs versus specific inputs.  Like above I test validate routines against *good* dictionaries and one test that should fail against a bad dictionary.  The other thing that I sometimes need to test is a side effect -- I called a function with bad input, part of what this function does is log when bad input occurs.  Did the function log the incident of bad data?  Generally this is where [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) comes into play.